# App Engine NDB alternative for db.StringListProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a need to store an ordered list of strings and am trying to start using ndb.  Previously I used a db.StringListProperty.  That's not available in ndb though, so what's the recommended alternative?  Looking at the [ndb types](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#types), I'm thinking I need to use the PickleProperty.  Is there something more appropriate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

Comment: Thanks.  If I use repeated=True, will the values always be in the same order when I read the entity back out?

Comment: Please do have a look at the cheat sheet, which has this kind of info: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/edit